# Handling Exception in Spring boot Application with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, spring-boot

I am building a REST API with Spring boot and DAO layer is implemented in Hibernate.I need to understand the correct way of throwing and handling Exception in the Application.Currently I am doing it in this way

```
@Repository
public class UserDaoImpl
{
     public getAllUsers() throws Exception
     {
          //get All Users from DB
    }
}

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl
{
    public getAllUsers throws MyCustomException
   {    try{
           userDaoImpl.getAllUsers();
         }
       catch(Exception e)
         {
             throw MyCustomException();
         }

   }         

}
```

and In Exception Mapper

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApplicationExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {   

@ExceptionHandler({MyCustomException.class})
  @ResponseBody
  public ResponseEntity<?> handleCustomException(Exception e) {
    log.error("", e);
    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<String, String>();
    error.put("message", e.getMessage());
    return new ResponseEntity<>(error, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE, MessageResource.getLogMessage("BAD_REQUEST_EXCEPTION"));
  }

}  

public class MyCustomException extends RuntimeException
{   
     ///// ....


}
```

So I have added throws clause (throws Exception) in DAO layer and catch at service layer and wrap it in Custom Exception(unchecked exception) and do not propogate the exception at controller layer.
Is this correct ? or there is some better way?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to have general `@ExceptionHandler({Exception.class})` for all cases that you don't want to handle specifically.
Also it's okay to create separate exception classes for situations that require custom handling.

It depends on what do you want to achieve.
About your case. Exception in **DAO** layer does not necessary mean that request was wrong or did not provide correct parameters. It could be mapping problems, DB access problems and etc. So I would not wrap it to my custom exception, or at lest wrap in to general `DataAccessException`, make good logging around that and return some general error code to the client.